How to fix Fixing Cross-site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability in ASP.NET Core MVC
I have the following code in my ASP.NET Core MVC code.
Security assessment tools have reported cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability at
return new JsonResult(new { response = sresponse, clientdata = model });

Please see the following code snippet:
public ActionResult DeleteSchedule(string scheduleid)
{
    string sresponse = "Success";
    ....
    ....            
        lstSchdeuleReports = new List<ScheduleReportModel>();
        ...
        model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstSchdeuleReports);

        return new JsonResult(new { response = sresponse, clientdata = model });
}

How do I fix this security vulnerability?
Thanks,
Gagan

By using System.Text.Json for serialization and ensuring that the data is properly encoded, you can mitigate the XSS vulnerability. System.Text.Json automatically escapes characters that are significant in HTML and JavaScript, making it safer to include user-supplied data in JSON responses.

@Rena using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;
public ActionResult DeleteSchedule(string scheduleid)
{
string sresponse = "Success";
lstSchdeuleReports = new List<ScheduleReportModel>();    

string model = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lstSchdeuleReports );

return Json(new { response = sresponse, clientdata = model});

}
